# Are there any tools to diff two VMWARE Windows XP images?

Tags: vmware-tools

Is there any tool that can summarize Registry and File differences between two VMWARE Windows XP images?

Comment: I am waiting to try Ashampoo on Tuesday most likely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything specifically for VMWare images, but if you can start up the VMs then why not use standard file & Registry diff tools?

For example, [RegShot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot) will allow you to take a snapshot of Registry and filesystem information, and compare it with another snapshot taken from a different machine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the VMs you want to compare are powered off, I would try using the VMware Disk Mount utility to mount their virtual disks and then use diff or your favorite file comparison tool on them. There is a little tutorial on using the utility here: http://www.petri.co.il/virtual_mount_vmware_virtual_disk_without_vmware.htm.

Good luck!

--jed

Answer (score 1):

For generic files you could use md5sum (or whatever GUI alternatives there are) and then diff that and for registry whatever tool that can dump it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you [Ashampoo Uninstaller](http://www.ashampoo.com/frontend/products/php/product.php?session_langid=2&idstring=0103)

It can create shanpshoot of registry and file system, export it to various formats. 
2 different snapshots can be visually compared within it, or you can even create installation out of it.

Superb tool, I use it for years even before Ahsampoo bought it, to make portable tools.